# How to plot GroupBy Dataframe with Matplotlib's Animation

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, plot

I'm currently trying to plot a groupby Dataframe using Animation over a video (taken using OpenCV), but due to Animation's form of plotting, I can't seem to figure out a way to plot this particular dataframe.

I managed to plot it by itself (without Animation) using the following code:

```
for ID, group in df.groupby('TrackID'):
        group.plot(kind='line', x='HeadX', y='HeadY', ax=ax,
                   label='ID ' + str(ID), rot=60)
```

What I'm currently trying:

```
def getImage():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(x_axis))
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(y_axis))
    return image


def drawPlot():
    global df_gb
    frame_list = [x for x in range(frame_id - 44, frame_id + 1)
                  if x > 0 and x <= frame_id]
    df = dataset_sorted[dataset_sorted['FrameID'].isin(frame_list)]
    df_gb = df.groupby('TrackID')
    return df_gb


def updatefig(*fargs):
    global frame_id
    ax.set_xlim(0, 1920)
    ax.set_ylim(1080, 0)
    frame_id += 1
    im.set_array(getImage())
    track.set_data(drawPlot())
    return im, track

dataset = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep=',', usecols=range(1, 9))
dataset_sorted = dataset.sort_values('FrameID')

unique_ids = dataset_sorted['FrameID'].unique()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)
h = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT) / 2
w = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH) / 2
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(w, h))

ax.xaxis.tick_top()
x_axis = list(np.linspace(0, 1920, num=16))
y_axis = list(np.linspace(1080, 0, num=9))

frame_id = 0

im = plt.imshow(getImage(), animated=True)
track, = ax.plot([], [], '-')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, interval=1,
                              blit=True, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

The video shows up, but the plot is never drawn.

So basically, how does one plot in Animation using df.plot() instead of passing data to an empty ax.plot()?

Comment: The line's `.set_data(x,y)` method expects arguements `x` and `y` to be lists or arrays of numerical data. It for sure does not expect a singe `GroupBy` object.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I know, but I also tried plotting directly (as I did in the first example) and it didn't work either. Because of what I'm plotting, I need a GroupBy Dataframe plot.

Comment: Sure, you may use `.groupby`. But don't supply this as argument to the function. Instead supply the x and y data to the function.

Comment: Viewing this from another angle, one could also say: You cannot update a single line with data that would form several lines. If you want to provide a [mcve] of the issue, one can surely look further into this.